# Alternative method to handle large patches generated from image dataset using tensor-flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Step 1:
I have a single tf-record which contains 4644 large images. 
I have to decode each image from the tf-record, 
convert them to patches of size 50

Step 2:
Once I create patches for all 4644 images. I have to write the created patches back to another tf-record which i will use it later for training the network.

I don't know how i can do the step 1 and 2 efficiently. i have written code for step 1 and 2 but the system hangs since i have total patches of size [369969,50,50,3] generated from 4644 images.

This is the code I have written

```
For decoding each image and convert to patches of size 50x50x3

dataset = (tf.data.TFRecordDataset('Image.tfrecords')
           .map(read_and_decode, num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls )  # step 2
           .map( get_patches_fn, num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls )  # step 3
           .apply( tf.data.experimental.unbatch())  # unbatch the patches we just produced
           .prefetch( 1 )  # step 6: make sure you always have one batch ready to serve
           )

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
patches_image = iterator.get_next()

init=tf.global_variables_initializer()

temp_patches_image=[]
image_batch_size=369969
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(0,image_batch_size):
      res=sess.run(patches_image)
      temp_patches_image.append(res)
    temp_patches_image=tf.stack(temp_patches_image)-------> This step 
                                                            causes my 
                                                            system to 
                                                            hang
    final_patches_image=sess.run(temp_patches_image)


Step 2:
 For writing the patches created to another tf-record

 create_data_record_patch(final_patches_image,'patches.tfrecord')


    def create_data_record_patch(patches, tfrecords_filename ):
        # Function to write all the filenames to a tf-record
        #   Input: file_names - list of filenames to be converted to tf record
        #          tf-records_filename- name of tf-file-record

        writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter( tfrecords_filename )
        total_batch_size=0
        for i in range(patches.shape[0]):

            height = patches.shape[1]
            width = patches.shape[2]

            img_raw = patches[i,:,:,:].tostring()
            example = tf.train.Example( features=tf.train.Features( feature={
                'height': _int64_feature( height ),
                'width': _int64_feature(width ),
                'image_raw': _bytes_feature(img_raw)}))

            writer.write( example.SerializeToString() )

        writer.close()
        return total_batch_size
```

Additional information: The above code works when i have a tf record of 50 images(generated ~5000 patches) instead of 4644 images. I know tf.stack is causing problem since it has to process all the 369969 patches, but I don't know any alternative method to create a single tf-record for all patches generated.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.